# How to backfrop entire page from inside child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So lets say I have this:

```
<div className='app'>
        <CustomComponent/>
 </div>
```

How would I backdrop the page with Material UI's backdrop component from inside of CustomComponent? Preferably without wrapping the main app div and passing a callback down to CustomComponent to do so.

Comment: could try using a portal https://mui.com/components/portal/#main-content, but you will still need to create a ref for that

Comment: What's wrong with this [example](https://mui.com/components/backdrop/#example)? It seems like what you want?